# Python school/ learning

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-module, file-writing

I was wondering if it is ok to ask for help with a learning thing... but here it goes.

In a course, I tried doing a thing I did in C# with ease. Idea is to take imaginary sales data to object array, sort it, drive it to bin file, json file, xml file, generate 10x  1000 batch random order IDs from data, search object to these with binary search and save all these to excel files so that in the end we have one bin file, one json file, one xml file and ten excel files with 1000-order rows each.

This was fairly easy to do in a procedural way but when trying multiprocessing, it goes really weird. First, it starts from up and goes all the way down to the line: `if __name__ == '__main__'`, which after it seems to start doing all same methods multiple times...

Here is my main:

```
import multiprocessing
import CsvReader
import DataContainer
import FileWriter
from datetime import datetime
import ExcelHandler

processes = []
container = DataContainer.DataContainer() #csv_reader.readFile())
csv_reader = CsvReader.CsvReader(r'C:\Users\jansse\Desktop\opiskelut\Python\finalCapstoneProj\100000 Sales Records.csv', container)
print(f'objects inside from the csv file: {datetime.now().time()}')
print(f"lines: {csv_reader.readFile()}")
print(f'begin sorting: {datetime.now().time()}')
container.sort_container()
print(f'sort done, multiprocessingStart {datetime.now().time()}')
fWriter = FileWriter.FileWriter(container)
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=fWriter.write_to_binary)
processes.append(p1)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=fWriter.write_to_json)
processes.append(p2)
p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=fWriter.generate_XmlFile)
processes.append(p3)
xlHandler = ExcelHandler.ExcelHandler(container)
p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=xlHandler.rollExcels)
processes.append(p4)


if __name__ == '__main__':

   for p in processes:
       p.start()

   for p in processes:
       p.join()
```

Here is an example of an method:

```
    def write_to_json(self):
        import json
        print(f'json writing start {datetime.now().time()}')

        try:
            jsonData = ''
            with open('objects.json', 'w') as outputfileJson:
                dEncoder = DataModel.DataEncoder
                json.dump(self.container.returnContainer(), outputfileJson ,cls=dEncoder)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Something happened: {e.__class__}, {e.args[0]}')
        finally:
            return (f'json writing completed {datetime.now().time()}')
```

and output looks like this. Why does it look like it starts going back to methods that prepare the data (like sorting) and why forexample it doesnt wait the json-write to complete although it I am joining processes after stating them? my debugging prints:

```
objects inside from the csv file: 06:27:33.139741
lines: 100001
begin sorting: 06:27:34.733476
sort done, multiprocessingStart 06:27:34.893071
objects inside from the csv file: 06:27:35.511050
lines: 100001
begin sorting: 06:27:37.111736
sort done, multiprocessingStart 06:27:37.283164
binarywriting start 06:27:38.886788
objects inside from the csv file: 06:27:39.482656
lines: 100001
begin sorting: 06:27:41.124737
sort done, multiprocessingStart 06:27:41.267926
json writing start 06:27:42.855922
objects inside from the csv file: 06:27:43.400854
lines: 100001
begin sorting: 06:27:44.938005
sort done, multiprocessingStart 06:27:45.097263
xml writing start 06:27:46.922682
objects inside from the csv file: 06:27:47.495836
lines: 100001
begin sorting: 06:27:49.225932
sort done, multiprocessingStart 06:27:49.397371
Excel writing start 06:27:51.089208
excelfile generating:0
excelfile generating:1
excelfile generating:2
excelfile generating:3
excelfile generating:4
excelfile generating:5
excelfile generating:6
excelfile generating:7
excelfile generating:8
excelfile generating:9
Excel writing completed 06:27:56.816604
xml writing completed 06:28:27.855510
```

Comment: Try wrapping these tasks in functions and passing it in to the process as args. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods the **spawn** section indicates that a new process will be started with everything needed. So maybe the way this is setup, Python sees it needs the `container` and the only way to get it is to run the lines above. If you did `Process(target=do_json, args=(fWriter,))` (making a function `do_json` that calls your obj's method on it's argument) that might prevent it from rerunning

Comment: put all of your main code under `if __name__ == '__main__': ...` scope.
I believe this is relative to the `Safe importing of main module` note in `Process` class documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming

Answer (score 0):

PYPL: that helped!!! Thanks :)

```
import multiprocessing
import DataContainer
import FileWriter
from datetime import datetime
import ExcelHandler
import CreateContainer

if __name__ == '__main__':

    creator = CreateContainer.CreateContainer()
    container = creator.createContainer()

    processes = []
    print(f'multiprocessingStart {datetime.now().time()}')
    fWriter = FileWriter.FileWriter(container)
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=fWriter.write_to_binary)
    processes.append(p1)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=fWriter.write_to_json)
    processes.append(p2)
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=fWriter.generate_XmlFile)
    processes.append(p3)
    xlHandler = ExcelHandler.ExcelHandler(container)
    p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=xlHandler.rollExcels)
    processes.append(p4)

    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

and now printing looks like this:

```
objects inside from the csv file: 06:05:59.502160
lines: 100001
begin sorting: 06:06:01.256706
containerReady 06:06:01.415215
multiprocessingStart 06:06:01.428252
binarywriting start 06:06:03.183367
json writing start 06:06:04.988768
xml writing start 06:06:06.725813
Excel writing start 06:06:08.561955
excelfile generating:0
excelfile generating:1
excelfile generating:2
excelfile generating:3
excelfile generating:4
excelfile generating:5
excelfile generating:6
excelfile generating:7
excelfile generating:8
excelfile generating:9
Excel writing completed 06:06:15.105672
xml writing completed 06:06:49.466709
json writing completed 06:08:15.298768
```

...and the reason why I didn't see print from write_to_json-method was because I plaid with returning variable from there and forgot to change it to print-method.